How to mock custom hook?
I want mock the getConversionList being called in useEffect. However since new to mocking need help
import { useConversion, useOtherHooks } from "@custom/library";

const [ getConversionList, conversionList ] = useConversion();

useEffect(() => {
  getConversionList();
}, []);

useConversion is graphql resolver
Using RTL. Trying to mock using jest.spyOn

What have you tried? If you google "jest mock custom react hook" you can see plenty of articles and SO posts demonstrating how to do this. What specific issue are you facing?

my concern is how do spy on getConversionList call?

@AKG use jest.mock to mock the module you're importing from and jest.fn to mock the function in that mocked module? https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-functions#mocking-modules

@DustInComp can you please provide a sample code for that?

Please see the jest docs and google it before asking.

@AKG Sample code is on the site I linked. Just, instead of axios, mock whatever graphql library is used by getConversionList and make it return a custom list you can then compare against. Maybe check out the partial mock example further down as well
